# Website uses Stack Overflow questions without giving reference

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this site](http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com) which displays Stack Overflow questions together with the best answer. So I was wondering whether it infringes the legal notice of Stack Overflow, as it does not give any references nor does it credit the users.

Also it appears to use a small set of avatars randomly applied to each question.